# Printing multiple separate pictures on one physical paper page with terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, printing

I have multiple `.png` files (for example: `pic_001.png`, `pic_002.png`... `pic_200.png`). These are basically separate pages of the book.

I want to create a single printing job, that will print 2 such pictures per one physical page, so it would look like a usual book spread.

I've tried to do this like this:

```
lp pic_001.png pic_002.png pic_003.png pic_004.png -d color-printer-1 -o sides=one-sided -o number-up=2
```

but it was printing only 1 picture per 1 page.

The same result with the for-loop:

```
for i in `seq 1 2 8`; do lp pic_00$i.png pic_00$[$i + 1].png -d color-printer-1 -o sides=one-sided -o number-up=2; done
```

but also this creates separate jobs per pair of pictures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than use `lp` directly, you could try using imageMagick, to make one image out of two or more images, and then print them

```
convert image1.png image2.png image3.pgn -append output.png
```

will put the images one above the other. If you replace `-append` by `+append`, the images will be side-by-side instead.

Answer (score 4):

Alternative method to the accepted answer is to use ImageMagick `montage` command which allows additional flexibility when defining the grid (tile) size:

```
montage -tile 1x2 -mode concatenate *.png page.png
```

The command will generate several page-*.png collages for each set of input files which fit on a single page.

Comment: add "-geometry +1+1" to get decent spacing between images

Answer (score 3):

Starting with

[image: Initial image]

To print one image multiple times set the file name.

```
terminal-where-image-is$ x="one_image.png"
```

To print **different** images "montaged" together on one page skip the above step and type them in below.

With **ImageMagick** installed; run

```
terminal-where-image-is$ montage -tile 2x4 -mode concatenate $x $x $x $x $x $x $x $x -border 1 page.png
```

which gives

[image: Multiple images]

Note:you can change the border number to get bigger or small borders, you can change the tile arrangement to get different row column configuration.

To print, (using `lp`)

1. List your printer options with

   ```
   terminal-where-image-is$ lpstat -p -d
   ```
2. Set printer with

   ```
   terminal-where-image-is$ lpoptions -d printer_name
   ```
3. Optional: to set PPI (pixels per inch) equal to the actual image property PPI

   ```
   terminal-where-image-is$ ppi=$(identify -format "%x" page.png)
   ```
4. Now to print as actual size (from ppi setting)

   ```
   terminal-where-image-is$ lp -o ppi=$ppi page.png
   ```

Answer (score 2):

`lp` doesn't know about image files; it can defer that to *device-specific* drivers, using options which exercise features "likely" to be supported by a variety of devices.  The [**`lp`** manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/lp.1.html) does not list any suitable option for your purpose.

Instead, if you want multiple image files to display on a single sheet of paper, you can do this by combining images into single-page images in the arrangement you want.  Programs such as ImageMagick are useful for this.

Further reading:

- [Is it possible to combine 4 Images into one png??????](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=14743)
- [How do I combine two or more images to get a single pdf file?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11163/how-do-i-combine-two-or-more-images-to-get-a-single-pdf-file)